# TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given) - Odoo v8 to Odoo v10 community

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-10

Consider this function:

```
@api.multi
def create_invoice(self):
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """

    self.ensure_one()
    if not self.sure:
        raise UserError(
            _("Validation error!"),
            _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
              " checking the option bellow!"))
    if (self.invoice_id and self.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
            self.invoice_id and self.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
        inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(self,
                                            self.invoice_id) 
    else:
        raise UserError(
            _('Validation error!'),
            _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
              " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window([inv_id], 'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

This is from a migration I'm doing from v8 to v10 community.

This method originally looked like this:

```
def create_invoice(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """ Create a invoice refund
    """
    context = context or {}
    wizard_brw = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    inv_id = context.get('active_id')
    for wizard in wizard_brw:
        if not wizard.sure:
            raise osv.except_osv(
                _("Validation error!"),
                _("Please confirm that you know what you're doing by"
                  " checking the option bellow!"))
        if (wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.jour_id and
                wizard.invoice_id and wizard.invoice_id.company_id.acc_id):
            inv_id = self.action_invoice_create(cr, uid, ids, wizard,
                                                wizard.invoice_id, context)
        else:
            raise osv.except_osv(
                _('Validation error!'),
                _("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
                  " and an account for damaged invoices"))
    return self.new_open_window(cr, uid, ids, [inv_id],
                                'action_invoice_tree1', 'account')
```

This method, checks if fields `acc_id` and `jour_id` are specified on `company_id`.

Right now, it throws me this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 638, in _handle_exception
return super(JsonRequest, self)._handle_exception(exception)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 675, in dispatch
result = self._call_function(**self.params)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 331, in _call_function
return checked_call(self.db, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/service/model.py", line 119, in wrapper
return f(dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 324, in checked_call
result = self.endpoint(*a, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 933, in __call__
return self.method(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/http.py", line 504, in response_wrap
response = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 866, in call_button
action = self._call_kw(model, method, args, {})
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/odoo-10.0rc1c-20161005/odoo/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 854, in _call_kw
return call_kw(request.env[model], method, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 681, in call_kw
return call_kw_multi(method, model, args, kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/.virtualenvs/odoov10/lib/python2.7/site-packages/odoo-10.0rc1c_20161005-py2.7.egg/odoo/api.py", line 672, in call_kw_multi
result = method(recs, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/kristian/odoov10/gilda/l10n_ve_fiscal_requirements/wizard/wizard_invoice_nro_ctrl.py", line 140, in create_invoice
_("You must go to the company form and configure a journal"
TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are getting Error because **UserError** takes only one argument & you have passed two arguments.

You need to use **ValidationError**

Odoo provide mainly three type of **exception Warning**.

1.**UserError**

2.**RedirectWarning**

3.**ValidationError**

**UserError & ValidationError** accept only one argument & only difference in wizard header message.

Ex:

```
  raise ValidationError(_('A transaction can\'t have a 0 amount.'))

  raise UserError(_('Error In Input Data'))
```

**RedirectWarning** accept three arguments.

```
  raise RedirectWarning(msg, action.id, _('Go to the configuration panel'))
```

**First** argument is Error message.

**Second** argument for redirect action you can click on link & redirect in configuration screen.

**Third** argument is Navigation message.

Comment: Awesome! Thank You very much